# Finding financial patterns of rows - sql with recursion

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

Let's consider I have a following table:

```
id    date        transaction_type     amount
 1    2017-01-01  deposit              30
 1    2017-01-01  deposit              20
 1    2017-01-02  withdrawal           -20
 1    2017-01-02  deposit              40
 1    2017-01-04  deposit              50
 1    2017-01-05  withdrawal           -100
 1    2017-01-07  withdrawal           -10
 1    2017-01-09  deposit              100
 1    2017-01-11  withdrawal           -50
 1    2017-01-21  deposit              20
 1    2017-01-22  deposit              30
 1    2017-01-31  withdrawal           -60
 2    2017-01-01  deposit              200
 ...  ...         ...                  ...
```

The dates in the table are ordered from the oldest to the newest for each id (timestamp is not visible). I would like to find how many times a specific transaction **pattern** took place:

deposit -> deposit -> withdrawal, and the time between the first deposit and the withdrawal is 7 days or less.

So for the customer with id = 1, I would have 2 such cases (the third one does not satisfy the time condition).

As a result, I would like to get the following table:

```
id   number_of_times
1    2
2    ...
...  ...
```

Is it something that can be done in SQL? Would I require recursion to get to the final table?

UPDATE:
As correctly pointed out, there are no intervening transactions - **but what if there were some?** Like any number of other transactions between 1st and 2nd deposit etc.

Comment: What about intervening transactions?

Comment: It's highly irregular to have duplicate "id" values in the table... is there a true "KEY"? Also, what's the order, date?

Comment: The key would be transaction_id, which I did not include above. The order is, first by id, then for each id by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have no intervening transactions:

```
select id, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lead(transaction_type) over (partition by id order by date) as next_tt,
             lead(transaction_type, 2) over (partition by id order by date) as next_tt_2,
             lead(date, 2) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date_2
      from t
     ) t
where transaction_type = 'deposit' and next_tt = 'deposit' and
      next_tt_2 = 'withdrawal' and
      next_date_2 < date + interval '7 day'
group by id;
```

Comment: What if there were intervening transactions, for example any number of _other transaction_ between the first and second deposit?

Comment: @codeless . . . This still works.  You would just need a `where transaction_type in ('deposit', 'withdrawal')` in the subquery.